# Product of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with a different topology on each factor

Tags: general-topology

Let $I=[0,1]$ with euclidean topology and let $J=[0,1]$ with a topology that have a base given by [0,1] and all the intervals of the type [0,a) with $a\in\mathbb{R}, 0<a\leq 1$.
Then, consider $X=J\times I$ with the product topology.

(a) For which $i\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ the space $X$ is $T_i$?

(b) Is $X$ a second countable topological space?

(c) If it exists, find a compact infinite subset of $X$ that is not closed.

(d) Is $Y=J\times \{0,1\}$ a connected subset of $X$?

My attempt is the following:

(a) The space $X$ is only $T_0$. To see that, I've proved that $J$ is $T_0$ and is not $T_1$, so the product can be only $T_0$ ($I$ is $T_4$ because it is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with euclidean topology that is $T_4$).

(b) $X$ is 2-countable because we can take the base for its product topology choosing an open set from $\{[0,a), a\in \mathbb{Q}\} \cup \{[0,1]\}$, that is countable and another open set from a countable base of $I$ that exists because $I$ is a subspace of a 2-countable topological space (euclidean $\mathbb{R}$). Therefore, the set of all the elements obtained as a product between an open set of the first family and an open set of the second family, is a countable base for $X$.

(c) The set $C=\{0\}\times [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{2}]$ works for me.

Are my answers correct? Any suggestions for the point (d)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) looks good. Maybe you should explicitly point out that every neighborhood of $\langle 0,0.5\rangle$ contains $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to show it's not $T_1$, and point out exactly one of $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ is contained in the open set $[0,\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})\times[0,1]$ when $x_1\not=x_2$, and exactly one of $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ and $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ is contained in the open set $[0,1]\times[0,\frac{y_1+y_2}{2})$ when $y_1\not=y_2$.

(b) looks good.

(c) is correct but needs more detail, similar to (a).

To approach (d), first note that $[0,1]$ is connected, and $\{0,1\}$ is a copy of the [connected Sierpinski space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000010/properties/P000036). What do you know about the product of connected spaces?

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it's all clear! The exercise has one more request that it's to establish whether $X$ is locally compact. I don't think that $X$ is compact because $J$ it's not compact. So, I wonder how to build a compact neighborhood using the compactness of $I$, any suggestions?

Comment: Is there an open neighborhood of $1\in J$ that doesn't cover all of $J$? If not, what can you conclude about $J$?